# how to delete text to end of line with curses

Tags: python, curses

How how to delete text to end of line ?

```
stdscr.addstr(5, 5, "Egestas Curabitur Phasellus magnis")
```

result screen: `Egestas Curabitur Phasellus magnis` # OK

```
stdscr.addstr(5, 5, "Elit metus")
```

result screen: `Elit metusrabitur Phasellus magnis` # Problem

Comment: Using `curses` here?

Comment: Looks like the [curses API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To delete to the EOL (*End Of Line*) use [`window.clrtoeol()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.clrtoeol):

**Example:**

```
import curses

window = curses.initscr()
window.clrtoeol()
window.refresh()
```

*I really recommend the use of the great [urwid](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/urwid) for any console/TUI programming however.*

**Update:** Bhargav Rao is right however; you have to call `window.refresh()` explicitly:

> Accordingly, curses requires that you explicitly tell it to redraw
>   windows, using the refresh() method of window objects. In practice,
>   this doesn’t really complicate programming with curses much. Most
>   programs go into a flurry of activity, and then pause waiting for a
>   keypress or some other action on the part of the user. All you have to
>   do is to be sure that the screen has been redrawn before pausing to
>   wait for user input, by simply calling stdscr.refresh() or the
>   refresh() method of some other relevant window.

Comment: If you are recommending urwid, you might consider showing complete examples with curses versus urwid, to illustrate.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `stdscr.refresh()` before your second line of code. This is made clear in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html)

> All you have to do is to be sure that the screen has been redrawn before pausing to wait for user input, by simply calling `stdscr.refresh()`

Answer (score 1):

Use `stdscr.refresh()` before `stdscr.addstr(5, 5, "Elit metus")`. And it will work.